# HTML5 Video time tracking

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have an HTML5 Video that plays on my site, I want to track the time of this video and have it execute a function or alert when the videos duration lasts 10 secs, 20 secs, 30 secs and so on.. I am a little stumped on how to do this? I can get it to alert every 10 seconds with jQuerys setInterval, but this is based on jquerys time paramter and not on the movie itself... this is what I have

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var video =  $('video#full-vid').get(0); //get the native browser source
  alert('video time:' + video.currentTime);
}, 10000);
```

Any ideas?

Basically this is the logic:

- Get Video Time
- If 10 seconds of video pass alert "10 Seconds have passed"
- If 20 seconds of video pass alert "20 Seconds have passed"
  so on and so on...

Thanks

Comment: you have to set a variable to keep track of your previous `.currentTime` and then subtract it from the current `.currentTime`

Comment: could you give me a quick example?

Comment: actually i misunderstood the question, i thought you wanted the time elapsed not the full current time every x seconds. see my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should be able to do like like

```
// set event listener to execute on timeupdate. This gets invoked every ~250ms or so
$('video#full-vid').on('timeupdate',function() {
  // use parseInt to round to whole seconds
  var ct = parseInt(this.currentTime);
  // only eval once per second inc, since timeupdate pops ~4 times per second
  if (this.lastTime!=ct) {
    // if current time is divisible by 10 then an inc of 10s has passed
    if (ct%10===0) {
      console.log(ct,'seconds have passed');    
    }
  }
  this.lastTime=ct;
});
```

**edit:**
if you are looking to do it at specific time intervals, you can do this:

```
// set event listener to execute on timeupdate. This gets invoked every ~250ms or so
$('video#full-vid').on('timeupdate',function() {
  // use parseInt to round to whole seconds
  var ct = parseInt(this.currentTime);
  // only eval once per second inc, since timeupdate pops ~4 times per second
  if (this.lastTime!=ct) {
    // do something at specified time elapsed markers
    switch (ct) {
      case 10 : 
        // do something
        break;
      case 20 : 
        // do something
        break;
    }
  }
  this.lastTime=ct;
});
```

Comment: Instead of an iteration every 10 seconds with ct%10===0, how do I just make an separate if statements that says, at 10 seconds do this... another that says 20 seconds, do this...

Comment: would it be if(ct == 10)??

Comment: @user2820604 yes you can do it that way, or you can use a `switch`. see edit

Comment: You sir, are a jquery ninja.. thank you for the help