# How to track video milestones in brightcove html5 player using adobe DTM?

Tags: dynamic, tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have a query regarding how to track milestones(Video) in brightcove player by using html 5.

There is already predefined events available for PLAY, PAUSE, STOP, but for the tracking the milestones i am unable to track it via DTM.

**Below mentioned is the code,which i have written for PLAY & PAUSE -**

**CODE -**

```
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('play',function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
    console.log('play');
  s.linkTrackVars='events,eVar21,prop21';
  s.linkTrackEvents='event22';
  s.eVar21 = myPlayer.mediainfo.name;
  s.prop21 = myPlayer.mediainfo.name;
  s.events = 'event22';
  s.tl(this, 'o');
});


videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('pause',function(){
     console.log('pause');
  var myPlayer = this;
  s.linkTrackVars='events,eVar21,prop21';
  s.linkTrackEvents='event21=6,event24';
  s.eVar21 = myPlayer.mediainfo.name;
  s.prop21 = myPlayer.mediainfo.name;
  s.events = 'event21=6';
  s.events = 'event24';
  s.tl(this, 'o');
});
```

Comment: Make use of the `timeupdate` event. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201693/html5-video-time-tracking/20202287#20202287).

Comment: Thanks @CrayonViolent.

When I am logging the time in seconds, using above mentioned code of yours,It’s giving me o/p as NaN. Could you please let me know, how I can log the time in seconds at specific intervals.
Like 25% 50% 75% of video play?

Comment: the answer i linked to shows how to do something at specific % intervals. As for the NaN, it sounds like you need to do `parseInt(value)` or `Number(value)` to convert it to a number (notice how I do that in my posted answer)

Comment: @CrayonViolent,

console.log msg at 25%,50% of video play is not getting populated

videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video').on('timeupdate',function() {
  // use parseInt to round to whole seconds
  var ct = parseInt(this.currentTime);
  // only eval once per second inc, since timeupdate pops ~4 times per second
  if (this.lastTime!=ct) {
    // do something at specified time elapsed markers
    switch (ct) {
      case 25 : 
        console.log('25% played');
        break;
      case 50 : 
        console.log('50% played');
        break;
    }
  }
  this.lastTime=ct;
});

Comment: Okay, the link I originally posted in my comment above is for generic html5 video tracking and also shows general concept of calculating time. It was a push in a general direction for you, since you did not post relevant code (and still have not).  Did you look at my posted answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Okay look, I'm not sure what exactly you are having trouble with, but posting new questions asking the same thing isn't going to help you. You keep posting these questions asking for help on milestones, but I have yet to see you pony up any code directly relevant to milestones. If you want actual help with understanding where you went wrong, then *post what you have actually tried* that is *relevant* to your question.

In general, here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/h07ayjxv/1/) of what you should be doing.

```
// keep track of events that are triggered to only trigger them once
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api')._isEventViewed = {};

videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('play',function(){
  if (!this._isEventViewed.play) {
    console.log('VIDEO: tracking PLAY event');
    /* tracking code here */
    this._isEventViewed.play=true;
  }
});

videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('pause',function(){
  if (!this._isEventViewed.pause) {
    console.log('VIDEO: tracking PAUSE event');
    /* tracking code here */
    this._isEventViewed.pause=true;
  }
}); 

videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('timeupdate',function(){
  var currentTime = Number(this.currentTime());
  var duration = Number(this.duration());
  var percentViewed = Math.floor((currentTime/duration)*100);
  var ev = this._isEventViewed;
  //console.log(currentTime,' / ', duration, ' - ',percentViewed);
  //console.log('_isEventViewed:',ev);
  switch(true) {
    case (!ev['25'] && percentViewed >= 25) : 
        console.log('VIDEO: tracking 25% MILESTONE event');
        /* tracking code here */
        ev['25']=true;
      break;
    case (!ev['50'] && percentViewed >= 50) : 
        console.log('VIDEO: tracking 50% MILESTONE event');
        /* tracking code here */
        ev['50']=true;
      break;
    case (!ev['75'] && percentViewed >= 75) : 
        console.log('VIDEO: tracking 75% MILESTONE event');
        /* tracking code here */
        ev['75']=true;
      break;
  } // end switch percentViewed
}); 

videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('ended',function(){
  if (!this._isEventViewed.ended) {
    console.log('VIDEO: tracking ENDED event');
    /* tracking code here */
    this._isEventViewed.ended=true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot crayon for your help.

Comment: How can milestones 25%,50%,75% can be triggered again if user reached the milestone for the same video again and if user slide the video maunaully towards specific milestone i.e. 25%, 50%,75%?

Comment: @PayalDaryani in the `ended` callback, you can do `this._isEventViews={}` to reset all the milestone flags. This will allow it track again if the visitor completes the video and watches it again.

Comment: @PayalDaryani sliding video scrub bar:*Most people do not track milestones visitors scrub back to. The provided code will track if you scrub *forward* to a milestone, but it will not track again if you scrub *backward* to a previous milestone. This is *by design* because tracking this sort of thing inflates your video metrics and brings very little actual value to reports.

Comment: @PayalDaryani If you still insist on tracking scrubbed milestones, then you can add a `seeking` callback listener. Within it, get the current `percentViewed` value (same as code within `timeupdate` and set all `this._isEventViewed` milestone events greater than `percentViewed` to `false`.  But as mentioned, this will inflate your milestones and will make for funky numbers in reports. e.g. people will ask why there are more 25% milestone hits than plays!

Comment: @PayalDaryani also, please upvote / mark solved if the answer was helpful and/or solved your issue.  This lets people know you are actually getting help on SO and they will be more inclined to help you in the future!