# Brightcove HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, tags, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

In Brightcove player - PlAY, PAUSE function is working properly, but when i have writing timeupdate function and wanted to trigger this event at specific intervals.(Milestones)

Here I am attaching the Sample Code of Brightcove test Video-

Please do me the support

**Below mention is the code of brightcove Test Video**

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Embed in page tester</title>
   <style>
    .video-js {
      height: 344px;
      width: 610px;
    }
    .video-js.vjs-mouse .vjs-big-play-button {
      background-color: red;
      opacity: .3;
    }
   </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="te-brightcove-trigger-video" data-video-id="5485986952001" data-account="1330301241001" data-player="H1KarKWEW" data-embed="default" data-application-id="" class="video-js" controls=""></video>
   <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/1330301241001/H1KarKWEW_default/index.min.js"></script> 
   </body>
   <script>
   //data-video-id : 5512582108001,  5485986952001
   </script>
   </html>
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201693/html5-video-time-tracking/20202287#20202287). If you still need help, posting a generic video script doesn't help anybody help you. Post what you have actually tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video time tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201693/html5-video-time-tracking)

Comment: Also, you have already asked this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403208/how-to-track-video-milestones-in-brightcove-html5-player-using-adobe-dtm).  Please do not make multiple posts asking the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track video milestones in brightcove html5 player using adobe DTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403208/how-to-track-video-milestones-in-brightcove-html5-player-using-adobe-dtm)